# Weekly Local Notification Showing Array Values - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, notifications

So let's say I have code like the below local notification code. It runs weekly. How do I change the alertBody string to cycle through an array of messages? My desired end result is that every week it shows array[i], where each time array[i] is incremented +1.

```
func weeklyNotifications () {
    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60)
    localNotification.alertBody = "Weekly array string"
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.category = "Message"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification can not cycle the body from an array, the only way is to schedule the notifications yourself (create one for each week) in a loop, and change the body accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Eli. What's the memory/CPU consequence of doing that? If I use a loop to schedule 30 different notifications, is that asking a lot from the CPU and memory?

Comment: @DaveG It can be consuming if you schedule a lot of notifications, please use this `[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:notification1, notification2, notification3]];`

Answer (score 0):

```
 for var i = 0; i < alertBodyMessage.count; i++ {
                    notification.alertBody = alertBodyMessage[i]
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
                }
```

you'll have to schedule a notification with alert message from your datasource